# How to set the path of Python by manually on Mac?

Tags: python, django

My question is about Python path setting on Mac:

When I open Terminal, entry the folders of the projects, and input following codes:

```
$python manage.py shell 
>>> from polls.models import Poll, Choice
```

Everything is OK. However , after I input some other codes, the shell is crashed. I don't know why. So I opened the Python IDLE, and input the same codes:

```
>>> from polls.models import Poll, Choice

    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    from polls.models import Poll, Choice
    ImportError: No module named polls.models
```

Some one told me that because of the path is set incorrect. So I want to use Python IDLE instead of Terminal, how to set the correct path by manually?

Comment: you have to make sure you did all the configuration about the settings(path, app install, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You may do:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(PATH_HERE)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'MY_PROJECT.settings'
```

If I run a script from my project sub directory I include these lines:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/..')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'MY_PROJECT.settings'
```

With Python IDLE you may create a config file.

Upon startup with the -s option, IDLE will execute the file referenced by the environment variables IDLESTARTUP or PYTHONSTARTUP. Files referenced by these environment variables are convenient places to store functions that are used frequently from the Idle shell, or for executing import statements to import common modules.